# How to make a UITextField disabled for deleting the custom number

Tags: ios, authentication

I have the app, that has a login form! And users are logging in with the telephone number.  The cell phone number always starts with the country code and it's possible to type it with +7 or with just 8.. I need a strict field, that will except only +7 sign. So how do I customize the UITextField so that user could only change the rest of the field?? I mean, I need the text field have the text property already filled with +7 number always and so that user won't be able to delete it, but just add his number. I hope, it's understandable ))) Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method of [`UITextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) and return `NO` for the first two characters (the prefix `"+7"`).

Something like

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return !NSEqualRanges(range, (NSRange){0,2});
}
```

This will prevent the first two characters in the text field to be modified at all.

Answer (score 2):

`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is what you will need to use.

[Class Reference for UITextField Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html):